# Changing just one border of a cell's (top, left, etc.) thickness.

Tags: html

Making a table, and I can't seem to figure out how to make a < t d >'s top border thickness greater than the other 3 sides even after all of the research I've done. I was hoping I could do something along the lines of  but can't figure it out. Ideas?

Comment: anything preventing you from just using border-top?...

Comment: Nope. Just inexperience to CSS classes until just now. Figured it out haha. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```css
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
   border-top: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <td>This is 1st td</td>
  <td>This is 2nd td</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>this is it</td>
  <td>it is this</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>another this is it</td>
  <td>another it is this</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I've made `td` top border `5px` and `red` color, you can change it accordingly.

**NOTE**: HERE I'VE ADDED TOP BORDER THICKNESS FOR ALL . IF YOU WANT FOR FEWER THEN YOU NEED TO CREATE CLASS FOR THAT AND APPLY CSS TO IT.

**POST IN COMMENT IF YOU'RE LOOKING FOR SOMETHING ELSE.**

[Running example](https://jsfiddle.net/u1ysx2w9/7/)